# Trying to use SUMIF matching two range of values

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

As shown in the image below, I'm trying to sum values based on range criteria.

[Exemple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcvg6.png)

Watch what I'm trying to do:
=SUMIFS(C:C, B:B, A:A)

Expected result: 14 (the result of A, B, C, and D)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or

```
=SUMPRODUCT(sumif(B:B,A:A,C:C))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may try:

```
=sum(ifna(filter(C:C,xmatch(B:B,A:A)))))
```

Comment: I believe it could work, but I think this formula is a bit advanced for my knowledge, it made me confused hehe.
The solution by Tom worked well over here :D